How to clear cache for get_terms()
I am calling get_terms() in a loop. I may modify the terms (add one) in an iteration of the loop. I need to be sure that the next iteration gets this added one. Specifically; I test for a child term of a parent. If it does not exist I add it and use it. If if does exist I use it. So; if I add it on the first iteration, say, I need to get it on the next iteration when I call get_terms. In pseudo-code:
for ($posts as $post_id)
{

    $term_id = wp_get_object_terms($post_id); //just one
    $child_terms = get_terms(array('parent' => $term_id));
    if (count($child_terms) < 1)
    {
        //create new term (based on the term of $term_id and add it to post
        $new_term_id = wp_insert_term('name', 'mytax', array('parent' => $term_id));
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $new_term_id);
    } 
    else
    {
        //assign $child_term :
         wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $child_terms[0]->term_id);
    }

} 

(I'm using pseudo-code because the whole thing is rather complicated; but this shows the flow).
I think that I should clear the terms cache at the top of the loop. I have found clean_taxonomy_cache() and wp_cache_flush() - the latter seems to clear the whole query cache? Which is better? Will clean_taxonomy_cache() do it? Is there anything else?
